# I can't change data of var element with JavaScript in Html

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me for change data of var element with `JavaScript`. I can't. I need If `check.innerText` changed to need change phone number.

```
function call(){

    var check = document.getElementById("locinfo").innerText;

    var tellnum = "tel:+998951441000";

    if (check=="Катартал") {
        tellnum = "tel:+998998047911";
    }
    else if (check=="Куйлик") {
        tellnum = "tel:+998951440010";
    }    }


    window.location.href = tellnum;
}
```

Comment: You need `setAttribute()`  not `window.location.href` that is used to navigate to another page.  You are trying to change the value of an html attribute.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic I think they're trying to make a phone call by redirecting to a `tel:` URL.

Answer (score 1):

It's seem like you have one spare `}`,
this should work.

```
function call(){

    var check = document.getElementById("locinfo").innerText;

    var tellnum = "tel:+998951441000";

    if (check=="Катартал") {
        tellnum = "tel:+998998047911";
    }
    else if (check=="Куйлик") {
        tellnum = "tel:+998951440010";
    }    


    window.location.href = tellnum;
}
```